# Cannot send email over tls using amazon ses and flask-mail

Tags: amazon-ses, flask-mail

Sending emails over ssl works fine but having trouble moving over to tls. It works fine on my local MacBook with TLS but while running the code on amazon Ec2, emails doesn't get sent. There is no error, it just drops my email silently. When I check the statistics then there it doesn't seem to change either. All that works fine with ssl.

I have check for errors in /var/log/httpd/error_log, but see nothing.

These are my email setting

```
# email server
    MAIL_SERVER = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'xxxxxxxx'
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = 'xxxxxxx@domain.com'
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?